# Making an If-Else Statement to Choose Color of a Shape in a Canvas

Tags: javascript

I am currently tasked with creating shapes on a canvas of different colors using a DOM. This is my first experience with the DOM. All the HTML and JS works fine if there was 1 color for all shapes, but I am trying to edit the function in question (drawShape(canvasID)) to have an if-else statement that determines the name of the canvasID and have a color associated with it.

Below is my first attempt at differentiating between two canvasId's to display either a red or blue rectangle.

```
function getElement(elementName) {

    var element = document.getElementById(elementName);
    return element;

}

function drawShape(canvasID){

    var canvas = getElement(canvasID);
    alert("Canvas is" + canvas);
    var ctx= canvas.getContext('2d');
    //ctx.rect(25, 25, 100, 100);
    //ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    //ctx.fill();
    if (canvas == "CANVAS1"){
        ctx.rect(25, 25, 100, 100);
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fill();
    }else if (canvas == "CANVAS2"){
        ctx.rect(25, 25, 100, 100);
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        ctx.fill();
    } 

}
```

As I said the rest of the program runs fine, and if I delete the if/else statements and use the lines that are currently comments, then the program will display all the rectangles as red. I just wanted advice on differentiating the colors. Any help is appreciated!

If editing to show all the JS and HTML is necessary just let me know!

Comment: `canvas` is a `Node` and you're comparing it to a string `canvas == "CANVAS1"`, you probably want to do this `canvasID == "CANVAS1"` instead.

Comment: Fixed it. Thank you very much!!! Such a simple change and fixed everything. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Recently had almost the same problem. 
Be sure to use "ctx.beginPath();" objects separator;

You can always replace a rect with a line.
See my code for changing color lines:

```
function lines(color1,color2) {

for (i = 0, j = 0; i <= 8 * 20; i += 20, j++) {
    ct3.beginPath();
    ct3.moveTo(300, 30 + i);
    ct3.lineTo(900, 30 + i);
    ct3.lineWidth = 20;
    ct3.strokeStyle = (j%2 != 0) ? color1 : color2;
    ct3.stroke();
}
```

}